# Why can't I find the tag [sql-server-2014]?

Tags: bug, tag-search

In the [tag search page](https://stackoverflow.com/tags), if you write `SQL` the tag `sql-server-2014` doesn't show up.

But if you search for `2014`, it appears.

Comment: The problem is that there is no pagination in the search result. Though you can find it by making the search more specific, i.e. searching for `sqlserver` or `sql-server`.

Comment: The tags are ordered by popularity. 'sql' is a fairly common component of tag names, and 2014 doesn't really do much from the point of view of a typical development that differs from what 2008 did -- so there's not as many questions about it.